# Perl String Modyifing

Tags: string, perl

Say I have a file called hello.txt which contains "Hello World!".
If I wanted to make a script which opened the file and read the contents (I know how to do that) and added stuff to the string, how would I go about doing this?

For example: Hello World would have '..' inserted at the start of the string/content, and then every 2 characters later, except at the end. Also consider the contents will not always be "Hello World".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already know how to read from a file, I take it your only real question is how to add `..` after every 2 characters of any given string:

```
my $string = "Hello World";
$string =~ s/^|(..)(?!$)/$1../g;
print "$string\n";
```

Output:

```
..He..ll..o ..Wo..rl..d
```

Though I can't imagine how that would ever be useful.

The regex looks for the start of string or two characters not followed by the end of the string, using negative look-ahead, and replaces all matches with any captured characters followed by two periods.

Comment: Thank you a lot. One more question, say HelloWorld is all attached, this will output .. at the very end. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @DavidG: I missed that part before I wrote my original answer. It's avoided with the negative look-ahead for the end of string added to my revised answer.